# How to remove particular part of a string in c# based on userinput?

Tags: c#, string

So, I'm trying to teach myself c# and so I'm doing some exercises. In this exercise, I am meant to create a program that outputs a sentence, the user gives input on what word they want to be removed from that sentence. The sentence is then printed without that word.

```
        string text = "Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
        Console.WriteLine(text);

        Console.Write("Which word would you like to remove? ");
        string userinput = Console.ReadLine();
        string newText = text.Replace(userinput, "");

        Console.WriteLine(newText);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

It replaces the characters with "", which seems like an artificial and cheat way of completing the exercise as the word is being replaced instead of removed. It also leaves a large space between characters.

Is there any alternative?

Comment: You could store the words in a `List<string>` and then remove the word from the list, or you could "walk" the string character-by-character, and remove words as you find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always split the text with string.split, which returns an array...to be joined on a space later on. It might be nice to check to see if the text actually contains the userInput...then you can say something like 'Couldn't find that ya dingus type a real word!'

```
if (text.Contains(userInput))
{
   newText = String.join(" ", text.Split(userInput));
} else ...
```

But I like the way you do it as well. To fix the double spaces you can always replace double spaces with a single space.

```
newText = newText.Replace("  ", " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're teaching yourself to *program*, then you probably want to avoid using any built-in methods like `Replace` or `IndexOf` or `Contains`. Otherwise, if you're just leaning a new language, then there's no issue with the code you're using, except to check if the word you've removed is followed by a space.

One way to do what you want without using built-in methods is to simply "walk" through the string in a loop, capturing each character into a temporary "word" variable. When you get to a space character, then if the word you've captured is not the one to remove, add it to a result string. If it *is* the word to remove, just ignore it and continue. At the end, you'll have all the words except the one that was supposed to be removed.

I've added comments to the example code below to better illustrate what I mean:

```
public static string RemoveWord(string input, string wordToRemove)
{
    // Validate aruguments, and exit early if they're null or empty
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return input;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(wordToRemove)) return input;

    string currentWord = "";  // This will hold the current word that we're building
    string result = "";       // This will hold the string we return to the caller

    // Examine each character in the input string
    foreach (char chr in input)
    {
        // If the character is a space, then...
        if (chr == ' ')
        {
            // If the word we've captured is not the word to remove, add it to result
            if (currentWord != wordToRemove)
            {
                result += currentWord + chr;
            }

            // Reset our word to an empty string since we've added or ignored it now
            currentWord = "";
        }
        // If the character is NOT a space, then...
        else
        {
            // Add this character to the word we're building
            currentWord += chr;
        }
    }

    // When we reach the end, do one more check in case there's a word remaining
    if (currentWord != wordToRemove)
    {
        result += currentWord;
    }

    // Return the input (without the wordToRemove) to the caller
    return result;
}
```

Example usage:

```
private static void Main()
{
    string text = "Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    string result = RemoveWord(text, "fox");

    Console.WriteLine(result);

    // Output: "Quick brown jumps over the lazy dog"

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

Comment: This is very good but a bit inefficient, because every time you do `string += anotherString` you are copying the hole string in the RAM. This is negligible in small strings, but it can be a pain with big strings. I would suggest to use `StringBuilder` or even `List<string>(input.Length)` with a single `string.Join` in the end.

Comment: Your answer uses `string += char` but I believe this work the same under the hood.

Comment: @Guilherme Yes, thank you. I'm aware of that, but it sounds like he's trying to learn programming so I was starting with something simple. Definitely there are more efficient ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .indexOf method to get the zero based index of the first occurrence of the replacement string.  Then using that information and the length of the replacement string, you can check for leading or trailing spaces and decide if you want to remove one or both of them.

Answer (score 0):

> your algorithm is okey but you can my algorithm, try steps

1. UserInput split by space ‘ ‘ then ToList and store in myWords List

   2. Search for remove word and remove word, use foreach and set condition if matching word remove  word by myWords.reomve(item);
   3. After list join use string.join(“ “, myWords); 
      **you understand or need code for more details ?  **